# In SAS, how do you search within a subpopulation, assess a value from certain columns, and return a single row with combined elements?

Tags: sas

Excuse me for the vague title, but I really don't know else how to word it.

How do I get from this...

> NAME--------------ID NO.-------------CITY---------------SCORE
>
> Name 1________222_________New York________27 
>  Name
>   1________222_________New York________58 
>  Name
>   1________222_________New York________71 
>  Name
>   2________333___________LA____________12 
>  Name
>   2________333___________LA____________92 
>  Name
>   2________333___________LA____________08

To This?

> NAME--------------ID NO.------------CITY--------------WORST SCORE
>
> Name 1________222________New York_________27 
>  Name
>   2________333___________LA___________08

I'd like to see the solution in both `PROC SQL` and `Data step`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a data step you could try something like this

```
proc sort data=mydata; by name id_no score; run;

data worst;
 set mydata;
  by name id_no;
   if first.id_no;
run;
```

The sort will put the lowest score to the first row for each name, then in the data step you are only selecting that first record for each name.

I'm not so eloquent with proc sql joins, so a quick and clumsy solution might look like

```
proc sql;

 create table ws as 
  select name, id_no, city, score as worst_score, min(score) as min 
   from mydata  
    group by name;

 create table worst as 
  select name, id_no, city, worst_score
   from ws where worst_score=min;

quit;
```

Or you could use `HAVING`, it might look something like this

```
proc sql;
 create table worst as 
  select name, id_no, city, score as worst_score 
   from mydata  
    group by name 
   having score = min(score);  
quit;
```

Comment: `having` has been available in SAS Sql for as long as I can remember, certainly since v8 and probably before that

Comment: You're, right. Igave it a go and it worked. Everyday's a school day. Thanks for that.